# stataRun extension of VSCode for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, stata

I have been using the "stataRun" extension of VSCode which allowed me to send code from VSCode to Stata and execute it using shortcuts. Since I have upgraded my system from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, this is not working anymore. Has anybody encountered the same problem and/or does anybody know a solution?

Comment: "not working anymore" didn't elicit a response. Perhaps no one who watches Stata questions here is using this OS.  I would try Statalist or StataCorp technical support.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Nick. Due to the relation to VSCode, I thought people on StackOverflow might be able to help me out. But I will try Statalist and tech support of StataCorp as well. Best.

Comment: You want advice from people in SO who use Stata in your way. That's the (possibly very small)  intersection of two sets, not their union.